# Apex controller Attempt to de-reference a null object error!

Tags: apex, visualforce, api, error

We've implemented an API using SOAP API, that connects to an external database, which we can search within our Salesforce org. I'm running into an 
Attempt to de-reference a null object error:

[image: Attempt to de-reference null object error:]

Here is the Visualforce Page:

```
<apex:page controller="EDSSearchController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock title="EDS Search">
        Enter search term here: <apex:inputText value="{!searchTerm}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!Search}" value="Search"/>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

And the Apex class:

```
public class EDSSearchController {

    public String searchTerm { get; set; }
    servicesEdrsEducationGovUkV17.EmployerLookupSoap a;
    EDS_Credentials__c edsCreds;


    public EDSSearchController() {
      edsCreds = EDS_Credentials__c.getValues('Default');
        a = new servicesEdrsEducationGovUkV17.EmployerLookupSoap();
    }

    public String getSearchTerm() {
        return searchTerm;
    }

    public PageReference search() {
        a.ByFreeText(searchTerm, false,'O','',edsCreds.API_Key__c);
        return null;
    }
}
```

What could be wrong with the code and where? (I'm quite new to integrations like this)

Many Thanks,
Natasha :)

Comment: May be you are getting "a" or edsCreds as NULL. Pls check its value by putting debug statements.

Comment: Turn on "Developer Mode" to get the line number in a stack trace so you have the exact location. See e.g. https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000968LIAQ for how to turn it on.

Comment: Debug `edsCreds` in constructor and check if you are getting a value for it. If it is `null` then that is the reason for your error.

Comment: I haven't debugged before or set up a log but I'll give it a go

Comment: Seems you have a custom setting named `EDS_Credentials__c`, verify that it exists in your sandbox.

Comment: @JayantDas yep it's a custom setting with a record too

Comment: Add this line as last line of constructor `system.debug(edsCreds)` and see what it  displays